# How to upload an array of images with Laravel properly

Tags: php, laravel, file-upload, laravel-5.8

I have a form like this:

```
<form action="{{ route('popups.store') }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    @csrf
    <div id="dynamic_field">
        <label>Date of showing</label>
        <input type="text" id="date" name="datep" class="form-control datepicker" value="" autofocus>
        
        <label for="title" class="control-label">Title</label>
        <input type="text" id="title" name="title" class="form-control" value="" autofocus>

        <label for="link" class="control-label">Link</label>
        <input type="text" id="link" name="linkp[]" class="form-control" value="" autofocus>

        <label for="bio" class="control-label">Text</label>
        <textarea class="form-control" name="bio[]" rows="3"></textarea>

        <label for="filep" class="control-label">Image</label>
        <input type="file" class="form-control-file" id="filep" name="filep[]">

        <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Submit</button>

        <a id="add" class="btn btn-info" style="color:white">Add new form</a>
    </div>                                      
</form>
```

As you can see, I have added a link with `id="add"` for adding additional form fields dynamically with javascript.

So it means a user can add several **images**, **texts** and **links**. And that's why I used `filep[]`, `bio[]` and `linkp[]`, as the name of those form fields (in order to save them as an array).

Then at the Controller, I added this:

```
  public function store(Request $request)
    {
        try{
            $data = $request->validate([
                'datep' => 'nullable',
                'title' => 'nullable',
                'linkp' => 'nullable',
                'bio' => 'nullable',
                'filep' => 'nullable',
            ]);
            
            $newPop = Popup::create([
                'datep' => $data['datep'],
                'title' => $data['title']
            ]);
            
            $files = $request->file('filep');

            if($request->hasFile('filep'))
            {
                foreach ($files as $file) {
                    $newImageName = time() . '-' . $request->name . '.' . $request->filep->extension();
                    $request->filep->move(public_path('popups'), $newImageName);
                    Popup::where('id',$newPop->id)->update(['image_path'=>",".$newImageName]);
                }
            }

        }catch (\Exception $e) {
            dd($e);
        }
        
        return redirect()->back();
    }
```

So for each image, I tried moving it into `public/popups` folder and then it should update the existing record of table with id of `$newPop->id`.

But it shows me this error:

**Call to a member function extension() on array**

Which is referring to this line:

`$newImageName = time() . '-' . $request->name . '.' . $request->filep->extension();`

So what's going wrong here? How can I upload multiple images with using array?

Comment: $file not $filep                       $newImageName = time() . '-' . $request->name . '.' . $file->extension();

Comment: @ZrelliMajdi I just changed it to `$newImageName = time() . '-' . $request->name . '.' . $request->file->extension();` but again shows me the error!

Comment: $file->extension() not $request->file . $file is an item file from your array

Comment: @ZrelliMajdi Can you write that as answer please

Comment: What is your database structure? `Popup::where('id',$newPop->id)->update(['image_path'=>",".$newImageName]);` you'll get only one image by this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this -

```
    if($files=$request->file('filep')){

    foreach ($files as $key=>$file) {
        $extension = $file->getClientOriginalName();
        $fileName = time().'-' .$request->name.'.'.$extension; // I don't know where did you get this $request->name, I didn't find it on your code.
       
        $created = Popup::create([
            'datep' => $request->datep[$key],
            'title' => $request->title[$key],
            'image_path' => $fileName
        ]);

        if($created){

            // $file->move('popups',$fileName); to store in public folder

            //  If you want to keep files in storage folder, you can use following : -

            Storage::disk('public')->put('popups/'.$location,File::get($file));

            // Dont't forget to run 'php artisan storage:link'
            // It will store into your storage folder and you can access it by Storage::url('file_path)
            

        }else{
            // Your error message.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Use fileName here -`Storage::disk('public')->put('popups/'.$fileName,File::get($file));`